# lists in python - TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, list, typeerror, non-type

I am semi-new to python programming and am very passionate about coding. I was just working on a little program which would just print out the amount of unique words in a list but for some reason I get a type error saying :

```
words = []
word = input('Word: ')
while word != '':
  words.append(word)
  word = input('Word: ')
words.sort()
unique_words = 0 
for i in range(0,len(words)):
  if words.count(words[i]) >= 2 :
    unique_words += words.count(words[i]) - (words.count(words[i]) - 1)
    words = words.remove(words[i])
  elif words.count(words[i]) < 2:
    unique_words += 1
print('You know ' + unique_words + ' unique word(s)!')
```

Comment: `words.sort()` returns `None` as the `words` list is sorted in-place. Use `sortedwords = sorted(words)` if you need to have a new list with the sorted results.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your help :))

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just compiled the code but it now says AttributeError: 'Non-Type' object has no attribute 'count'

Comment: @MartijnPieters do you have any help for this problem as well ;)

Comment: Isn't it clear still that you do *not* need to store the result of `words.sort()`? You still have the return value somewhere and are confusing it with the sorted list.

Comment: How bout now @MartijnPieters? I still get the:

Comment: `words.remove()` also returns `None` for the same reasons.

Comment: Ohh k so the general rule for attributes like: list.append() is that they need their own line

Comment: @MartijnPieters there are still issues with: if words.count(words[i]) >= :

Comment: @MartijnPieters apparently the variable i goes out of the list words index but funny enough, if I print i, it leaves me with the all the indexes of the list words

Comment: You are *removing* words from the list, but your range will not update. Use a `while` loop, perhaps. `while i < len(words): i += 1`. Not that I've at all looked at your algorithm, which probably can be vastly improved with a different approach. Perhaps ask a proper, new question? This back and forth in the comments doesn't really work. Mind you, you could start with some debugging skills (like `print`ing your variables, using `repr()` perhaps) and isolating different expressions, trying them out in your interpreter, so you understand what is happening.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. You have solved my problem :D Just one question: Do you know how i can learn to create better and more simplified algorithms?

Comment: Study computer algorithms. Perhaps something like the [MIT Intro course](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/index.htm) or the [Khan Academy materials](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms) to name two extremes in expectations and expected levels of required knowledge.